# multiplication result is negative zero

Tags: python

can someone tell me why the output of the code mentioned below is negative zero??

a  * b  = -0

here 'a' is of type long,  b is an object of decimal class.....and if a=-28 and b=0, then the output is -0

Answer (score 7):

From the Python [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#special-values) docs:

> The signed zeros can result from
>   calculations that underflow. They keep
>   the sign that would have resulted if
>   the calculation had been carried out
>   to greater precision. Since their
>   magnitude is zero, both positive and
>   negative zeros are treated as equal
>   and their sign is informational.

Comment: what's the recommended way to handle such results which are effectively 0 but which have this "extra" information?  Like if I want to use these in user-facing output

Comment: @Bodhi, I'm not quite sure what you mean. If you are asking what information to provide to the user, I'm afraid only you can decide that. But perhaps you are asking how to get the information in a way that doesn't require parsing the string representation? For that, the `as_tuple` method is nice: `repr(decimal.Decimal('-0').as_tuple())` outputs `'DecimalTuple(sign=1, digits=(0,), exponent=0)'`, where `DecimalTuple` is a custom `namedtuple`. For positive `Decimal` objects, `sign = 0`; for negative, `sign = 1`. So `decimal.Decimal('-0').as_tuple().sign == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This explains it all :

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

it's something very close to zero, but on the minus side, that is why this happens.

Comment: Um, no … OP specified that this is `long` times `decimal.Decimal`. There’s no floating-point issue here, and the result is not very close to zero, it **is** zero, but with a negative sign.